# Select between two dates when there is overlapping

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have these data in my view

```
ID       event_start               event_end           
499 2021-07-13 00:00:00.000 2021-07-13 00:00:00.000 
499 2021-07-15 00:00:00.000 2021-07-15 00:00:00.000 
499 2021-07-14 05:00:00.000 2021-07-14 06:00:00.000 
499 2021-07-14 02:00:00.000 2021-07-14 03:00:00.000 
499 2021-07-14 07:00:00.000 2021-07-14 09:00:00.000
```

So I have parameters as @date_start and @date_end and would like to select like this:

```
DECLARE @date_start datetime2 = '2021-07-14 07:00', @date_end datetime2 = '2021-07-14 08:10'

Select ID, t1.event_start, t1.event_end from Table1 
WHERE event_start >= @date_start AND event_end <= @date_end
AND ID=499
```

That will give me no returned result. But my goal is to get the last row.

```
499 2021-07-14 07:00:00.000 2021-07-14 09:00:00.000
```

since this row starts at 7 and finishes at 9 which will cover the @date_start and @date_end period. How could I do that?

Also if I changed @date_start and @date_end to this:

```
DECLARE @date_start datetime2 = '2021-07-14', @date_end datetime2 = '2021-07-14'
```

It should return

```
499 2021-07-14 05:00:00.000 2021-07-14 06:00:00.000 
499 2021-07-14 02:00:00.000 2021-07-14 03:00:00.000 
499 2021-07-14 07:00:00.000 2021-07-14 09:00:00.000
```

because all three row happened on the same day but just different time.

Thank you

Comment: You are currently asking the row range to fall into the given range, when you actually want the given range to fall into the row range. Hence: `WHERE @date_start >= event_start AND @date_end <= event_end` if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Yes that works in one case. But it doesn't work in the second case when I do not have time in my start_date and end_date.

Comment: Correct. That wouldn't work for the second example, as the given range means midnight (a date without a time is interpretetd as 00:00:00). And if the given range were the whole day (00:00 - 23:59'), then none of the rows would cover that range either.

Comment: I think you must define exactly what rules you want to apply, because obviously sometimes you want a range covered and other times not. It seems that if two datetimes are given (i.e. at least one f the two has a time > 00:00?), then the given range must fit completely into the row range. And if only dates are given (no time part or time = 00:00), then the row range must at least contain one second of each of the two given dates? Be precise with the rule definition, then put this into SQL step by step.

Comment: It's not clear if you want the date range in the parameters to fall within the date range in the table, or if you want the date range in the table to fall within the parameters, or if you want any date range in the table that overlaps (even partly) with the parameters. These are three different things, be clear about which one youi want.

Comment: sorry, I would be happy to update the question to make it clearer. The goal is to check whether there will be any conflicts or overlapped with existing bookings with the parameters date_start and date_end.

Comment: for example if DECLARE date_start datetime2 = '2021-07-14 07:00', date_end datetime2 = '2021-07-14 08:10', then I don't allow another booking from 7 to 8 cause it's going to overlapped existing booking from 7 to 9. Same thing if someone wants to book for the whole day on 2021-07-14, it's not possible either cause there are bookings already. If the booking is from 6 to 7, then it should be ok. –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you actually want to check for any overlaps of the date ranges in the table with the date range specified in the parameters.

Assuming that it doesn't matter if two intervals butt-end each other (say 07:00-08:00 and 08:00-09:00), **you need to do an interval check like this `start1 < end2 AND end1 > start2`**

```sql
DECLARE @date_start datetime2 = '2021-07-14 07:00', @date_end datetime2 = '2021-07-14 08:10'

SELECT
    ID,
    t1.event_start,
    t1.event_end
FROM Table1 
WHERE event_start < @date_end AND event_end > @date_start
  AND ID = 499;
```

Comment: That's helpful. With a bit manipulation on the date_end when there is no time, I was able to achieve both cases. SET new_date_end = DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, date_end, DATEADD(DAY, 1, date_end)) -1 , date_end)

Comment: I came across one issue if you could help. If I have this data in my table. 499 2021-07-15 00:00:00.000 2021-07-15 00:00:00.000. DECLARE date_start datetime2 = '2021-07-15', date_end datetime2 = '2021-07-15' would not return anything until I changed  event_end >= @date_start

Comment: But if I changed it that way, I would not be able to make booking say 07:00-08:00 and 08:00-09:00 cause it's going to say there is a booking. It seems I can have one or the other but not both.

Comment: I suppose it all depends on how you define an interval. Personally I would say an interval with no time in it can't overlap anything, but yes, your change is a valid option.

Comment: Is there a way I could achieve both? event_end > date_start allows me to make booking 07:00-08:00 and 08:00-09:00 but would not pick up  2021-07-15 to 2021-07-15. event_end >= date_start will returned   2021-07-15 to 2021-07-15. but makes booking 07:00-08:00 and 08:00-09:00 impossible.

Comment: Perhaps you need to redefine your data: `2021-07-15 00:00:00.000` is a date *and* a time, use it as such. So if the whole day needs to be booked out then make the end time `2021-07-16 00:00:00.000`. You could also potentially consider the start of the interval as inclusive and the end exclusive

Answer (score 0):

First thing to bear in mind, are your datetimes in DATETIME type?

If so, let's check the first case.

1.To see whether a datetime/timestamp is contained in a range, we specify the following WHERE clause:

```
WHERE 
  event_start <= '2021-07-14 07:00:00' and
  event_end >= '2021-07-14 08:10:00'
```

**1. OUTPUT**

```
id  event_start             event_end
--- ----------------------- -----------------------
499 2021-07-14 07:00:00.000 2021-07-14 09:00:00.000
```

In case your data is not in DATETIME/TIMESTAMP type, this might not work.

2.Here, you change the condition, since you want all the stuff that happened during a whole day. Therefore, the WHERE clause looks like this:

```
WHERE 
  event_start >= '2021-07-14' and
  event_end < '2021-07-15'
```

**2. OUTPUT**

```
id  event_start             event_end
--- ----------------------- -----------------------
499 2021-07-14 05:00:00.000 2021-07-14 06:00:00.000
499 2021-07-14 02:00:00.000 2021-07-14 03:00:00.000
499 2021-07-14 07:00:00.000 2021-07-14 09:00:00.000
```

Hope it helped!

Comment: Thank you and yes they are in datetime2 format. So that should not be an issue. My main point is to check my database to see if a selected start date and end date by the users will be conflicted with any existing booking. Is there a way to do this with the data I show you?

Comment: for example if DECLARE date_start datetime2 = '2021-07-14 07:00', date_end datetime2 = '2021-07-14 08:10', then I don't allow another booking from 7 to 8 cause it's going to overlapped existing booking from 7 to 9. Same thing if someone wants to book for the whole day on 2021-07-14, it's not possible either cause there are bookings already. If the booking is from 6 to 7, then it should be ok.

Comment: The main points of your questions were already answered. Shouldn't you consider to post another question, asking exactly what you are telling me here?